# Finding all the number combos in array that add up to input number

Tags: java, arrays

Hey I'm working on figuring out an algorithm that takes a user-entered number and then goes through an array of size 50 filled with random numbers between 1 and 100 and finds all the combinations of numbers that add up to the input number.

For example, given an array of integers [3,6,1,9,2,5,12] and being passed the integer value 9, you would return [[3,6],[6,1,2],[9],[3,1,5]].  Order of returning the results in the array does not matter, though you should return unique sets (ie. [6,3] and [3,6] are the same and only one should be returned).  Also, the individual results should be in the order they are found (ie [6,1,2] should be returned, not [1,2,6]).

As I've started writing code, the first solution that I came to seems extremely in-efficient. I'm currently trying to separate each combo into it's own array, and every time a number gets added to the array, a check is done to see if the numbers equal the input, are still less than, or go over it. It's not working properly, and I feel like this might be an inefficient way to do it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      List<Integer> combo = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      int counter = 0;
      int current = list[i];
      if (current == input){
        System.out.println(i);
      }
      else if (current > input) {
        continue;
      }
      else if (current < input) {
        combo.add(current);
        if (combo.size() >= 2) {
          for (int j = 0; j < combo.size(); j++) {
            counter += combo.get(j);
            if (counter == input) {
              System.out.println("Success");
              break;
            }
            else if (counter < input) {
              continue;
            }
            else if (counter > input) {
              break;
            }                 
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: If we should ignore some parts of the code, why including these parts at all ? Not saying it is unreadable as is, but this is still unnecessary

Comment: Sure, I went ahead and took them out

Comment: The algorithm has to be inefficient, as it's a variation on the Subset Sum problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: It'd probably be worth sorting the random numbers since you would only need the subset of numbers <= to the user's number and would be able to stop when the combo's sum is >.

Comment: Okay, I think there are still some of them remaining :). Anyway, I did not look the text of the question and I did not read all the code but I can already telle you that your control-flow is very weird in the inner `for` loop. It can be made much better (basically a single `if` with a single `break`)

Comment: Are you looking for only three?

Comment: I'm looking for all possible combinations that add up to the input number.

Comment: First off, the set is composed of random integers, not random numbers.  Can the list of random numbers contain repeats.  For example, could you have (1, 1, 1, 2, 4. 6, 8, 16)?  Can numbers in the set be used more than once?  It looks a set of 8 random integers only creates 8 combinations, with each combination being composed of the values from position 0 to position n.  If each value can only be used once, it would appear to be a tree search, with each level of the tree indicating the absence or presence of a value.  When you exceed the target value, prune the whole tree below the node.

Comment: Are all of the random integers positive?  If so, that reduces the complexity below that of the subset sum problem.

Comment: The list has to be filled with unique integers, so no repeats. And yeah, they have to be positive

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea, I don't have a working code. Try to use recursion, test all combinations with the biggest possible number plus all the rest without it. Function like: Sums(Number, maxN), (maxN is maximum number which we can take - in first call it's 9)
For your example would be:
1. As suggested, sort them and cut bigger than input.
2. Check if the maxN is greater than the minimum required to make a sum, in your example it is 5 (can't make 9 from numbers smaller than 5 in your set); if it's not return (base case).
3. Is maxN equal tu input? (9 in first call)
 a) Yes - first solution subset [9] + Sums(Number, dec(maxN)) (dec(maxN) will be 6 in first call)
b) No - recursively check if 'Number - maxN' could be built from numbers from your set, Sums(Number - maxN, dec(K) or max number of 'Number - maxN' (depends what is smaller)) + Sums(Number, dec(maxN)) - add the rest.

Here is code to count only, ways to write a number as  sum of squares, it passed HackerRank tests:

```
import math
def minArgument(x):
    s = 0
    i = 1
    while s < x:
        s = s + i * i
        i = i + 1
    return i - 1
def maxPower(a):
    return math.floor(math.sqrt(a))
def sumOfSquares(M, K, cnt):
    if M < 1:
        return cnt
lowerLimit = minArgument(M)
    if K < lowerLimit:
        return cnt
    else:
        if K * K == M:
        return sumOfSquares(M, K - 1, cnt + 1)
    else:
        return  sumOfSquares(M, K - 1,sumOfSquares(M - K * K,  
                    min(maxPower(M - K * K), K - 1), cnt))
```

After easy change, this gives you number of solutions. I don't see how to build a list with combinations as a return value now...